# css opacity didn't change in setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, css, settimeout

I'm trying to make a Simon Game and here is the code in codepen.
The problem is the opacity didn't change while the code executed.
It's pretty strange that the html text got changed but opacity didn't.
Can anyone point out where I did wrong? code is in line31.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".sw-slot").click(function(){
  $("#pwr-sw").toggleClass('sw-on');
   $('.count').toggleClass('led-off');
  if($( "#pwr-sw" ).hasClass( "sw-on" ))
    {
      $("#start").click(function(){
        console.log("game started");
        var myGame= new Game();
        var gameCount = 3;
     //computer move 

      for (var i = 1; i <= gameCount; i++) {
          (function() {
              var j = i;

             var currentArray = myGame.computer.slice(0, gameCount);
              var sectornumber = currentArray[j-1];  

            setTimeout( function timer() {
                  console.log("now 0.5");
                   $(".count").text(j);                   
                  $("#sector-"+sectornumber).css('opacity', 0.1);  
              },j*2000 ); //这一行将i*1000改为j*1000也行，并不影响
              setTimeout( function timer1() {
                  console.log("now 1");
                  $("#sector-"+sectornumber).css('opacity', 1);  
              },j*2000); //这一行将i*1000改为j*1000也行，并不影响
          })();
      }
      console.log("TIMEOUT FISNIHED")
   //waiting for user input 
      })



    }
  else
    {
      console.log("game ended");
    }
})

function Game(){
  this.computer=[ ];
  this.userInput=[ ];
  for(var i =0;i<20;i++)
  {
      this.computer.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4));
  }
};  
})
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/amberwjq/pen/prOVKw?editors=1111 Here is the project link in codepen

Answer (score 0):

It's not that it's not working, it's that you're setting opacity to 1 at the same time as you're setting it to 0.1.

```
setTimeout( function timer() {
    console.log("now 0.5");
    $(".count").text(j); 
    $("#sector-"+sectornumber).css('opacity', 0.1);  
},j*2000 ); //这一行将i*1000改为j*1000也行，并不影响

setTimeout( function timer1() {
    console.log("now 1");
    $("#sector-"+sectornumber).css('opacity', 1);  
},j*2000); //这一行将i*1000改为j*1000也行，并不影响
```

If you want to start the second timer after the first, you need to put it inside the first callback:

```
setTimeout( function timer() {
    console.log("now 0.5");
    $(".count").text(j); 
    $("#sector-"+sectornumber).css('opacity', 0.1);  

    setTimeout( function timer1() {
        console.log("now 1");
        $("#sector-"+sectornumber).css('opacity', 1);  
    },j*2000); //这一行将i*1000改为j*1000也行，并不影响

},j*2000 ); //这一行将i*1000改为j*1000也行，并不影响
```

Comment: Hi Camille,Thanks for your reply.Using your suggested code, the sequence is not correct as you can see from the console.                                            "now 0.5"
"now 0.5"
"now 1"
"now 0.5"
"now 1"
"now 1"

Comment: Yes, I noticed that setting opacity to 1 almost happened at the same time as setting it to 0.1.But why does it happen? it has a j*2000 timeout there to have some delay.